# How can I combine these two for loop statements?

Tags: c++, for-loop, arduino, led

Hi I'm using an Arduino to have a column of 4 leds streak across from left to right then back across on a 4x16 led panel.
Currently I am using two for loop statements to make this happen but I'm wondering if there is way to combine the two loops or something so that left to right to left is all encompassed in one statement.
Thanks.

```
int row1 = 0;
int row2 = 0;
int row3 = 0;
int row4 = 0;
int row1r = 0;
int row2r = 0;
int row3r = 0;
int row4r = 0;

void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<LED_TYPE, DATA_PIN, COLOR_ORDER>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (! Serial);
}

void loop() {
  // Left to Right
  for (row1 = 0, row2 = 31, row3 = 32, row4 = 63; row1 <= 15 && row2 >= 16 && row3 <= 47 && row4 >= 48; row1++, row2--, row3++, row4--) {
    leds[row1] = CRGB::Blue;
    leds[row2] = CRGB::Blue;
    leds[row3] = CRGB::Blue;
    leds[row4] = CRGB::Blue;
    FastLED.show();
    delay(30);
    leds[row1] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[row2] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[row3] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[row4] = CRGB::Black;
  }
  // Right to Left
  for (row1r = 15, row2r = 16, row3r = 47, row4r = 48; row1r >= 0 && row2r <= 31 && row3r >= 32 && row4r <= 63; row1r--, row2r++, row3r--, row4r++) {
    leds[row1r] = CRGB::Blue;
    leds[row2r] = CRGB::Blue;
    leds[row3r] = CRGB::Blue;
    leds[row4r] = CRGB::Blue;
    FastLED.show();
    delay(30);
    leds[row1r] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[row2r] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[row3r] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[row4r] = CRGB::Black;
  }
}
```

Comment: Start by fixing both of your existing loops so they use only one loop variable. Using four simultaneous loop variables is too convoluted, and confusing. Because all four rows have a simple mathematical relationship, between them, using one variable and computing the address of the remaining three rows is trivial. Once you simplify both loops so that they are much simpler and use only one variable, how to combine both loops should then be very obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a better algorithm approach for this requirement would be treating the led matrix as an array of 16 column then defining a function that takes column index and illuminates leds correspondent to that column , each led shall be defined as function of the variable columnIndex then looping over the 16 columns in the void loop .

1)

[image]

```
void illuminateColumn(columnIndex)
{
    //illuminate leds[4*columnIndex]
    //illuminate leds[4*columnIndex+1]
    //illuminate leds[4*columnIndex+2]
    //illuminate leds[4*columnIndex+3]

    delay(30)

    //blacken leds[4*columnIndex]
    //blacken leds[4*columnIndex+1]
    //blacken leds[4*columnIndex+2]
    //blacken leds[4*columnIndex+3]

}

void loop()
{
  for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
   {
     illuminateColumn(i);
   }

  for(int j=15;j>0;j--)
   {
     illuminateColumn(i);
   }

}
```

2)

[image]

```
void illuminateColumn(columnIndex)
{
//illuminate leds[63-columnIndex]
//illuminate leds[47-columnIndex]
//illuminate leds[31-columnIndex]
//illuminate leds[15-columnIndex]

delay(30)

//blacken leds[63-columnIndex]
//blacken leds[47-columnIndex]
//blacken leds[31-columnIndex]
//blacken leds[15-columnIndex]

 }

 void loop()
  {
    for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
     {
       illuminateColumn(i);
     }

    for(int j=15;j>0;j--)
     {
      illuminateColumn(i);
     }

   }
```

Comment: The led matrix is in this format:
63 62 61 60 59 58 57 56 55 54 53 52 51 50 49 48

32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47

31 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

What changes would this make?

Comment: Edited the answer to include your case